# Where do I start when learning how to make a secure but easy to maintain PHP registration form?

Tags: php, pdo

I've been looking for a little while lately but cant really find a secure registration form. Everything I find got comments like `"open for XSS"`, or `"Open for SQL injections"`. I know what both the attacks means and how they are done (at least mainly how they are done), but finding a secure guid or already existing form is harder than I thought. The best I could find was a `PDO` one, worked great but at the end the author wrote that it should not be used for bigger projects (can't find the link sorry).

Before I started searching yesterday, I wrote a list of things I wanted with this form. like minimum password length, confirm password, etc. In a hope that I would be able to find a easy to understand form that I could build upon and learn from.

Could someone post a basic secure PHP or PDO script that is easy to use, and give me some information about what I should or shouldn't do?

Comment: This question is clearly off-topic according to the "what to ask here" definition. It asks for a recommendation.

Comment: I have a tutorial to [build a complete web app](http://ilovephp.jondh.me.uk/). It does not deal with creating a registration form, but it shows how to combat XSS and SQL injection in the context of a PHP/PDO app. Creating a registration form on top of that would be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a framework such as [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/) or [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) to protect yourself from XSS and SQL injection.
Framework helps you with useful library, helpers and database connecter. 
But in the end all you got to do is validate each entry of your site and bind your parameters when creating SQL queries.
to validate email you can use the email filter from filter_var:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
  echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```

or simply use a regex :

```
if(filter_var($string,FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/((\w)@(\w)\.(\[a-z]{2-4}/")))){
    echo 'Valid Email';
} else {
    echo 'invalid email';
}
```

And then for your database, simply prepare your statement and bind your parameters.

```
$stm = mysqli_prepare('SELECT password FROM user WHERE email = ?')
$stm->bind_param('s', $email); // s for String
$stm->execute();
```

I suggest to go read on those subject, here are a few site.
[Official PHP doc on Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
[W3School on Mysqli](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)
[Official PHP doc on filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)
[W3School on filter_var](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_var.asp)
[regex101 to learn regexp](https://regex101.com/)
P.S. the regexp for the email i wrote is not the best one.

Comment: This provides a very questional sense of security if followed.

Comment: The advice of "use a framework" to combat SQL injection and XSS needs a caveat: they can help, but unwitting users can still add these security issues. It is better to understand _how_ to remove them, rather than relying on framework magic.

Comment: I know framework arn't magical but they at least help a bit with easy to use library. But i agree it does not do the works for you.

Comment: I will look into it, btw i found the PDO form i was talking about, ( http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html ) at the last page the author sais "this code is not production ready"

Comment: Yea it's difficult to take code off the internet and make it work perfectly, you usualy have to understand it and then make your own based on your needs.